# How do I exclude specific tests by default but include them if activate a a certain profile?

Tags: java, maven

Right now I am aware that if I use

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/Benchmark*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I will be able to skip the tests I don't want to run. However, I want to have a specific profile whereby the above excluded tests will run if i build using that particular profile. I've tried

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>benchmark</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                            <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

along with the above but it seems like it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by *it doesn't work*? How did you activate the profile?

Answer (score 2):

Maven is merging your configurations together instead of overwriting as you expect it to, so your final configuration with the profile active would look like:

```
<configuration>
    <includes>
        <include>**/Test*.java</include>
        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
        <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
    </includes>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>**/Benchmark*.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
</configuration>
```

There's no need for all those default `<include>`s. They're [already there anyway](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html). Just put `<excludes/>` to tell Maven you want to stop doing the excludes that you specified in the basic POM. I.e., in your profile, just say:

```
<configuration>
    <excludes/>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Using `<excludes/>` at profile level is not overriding it's default value.

Comment: Try adding `combine.self="override"` to the `<excludes>` element (as described in [Maven POM reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins) and [Sonatype Blog post](http://blog.sonatype.com/people/2011/01/maven-how-to-merging-plugin-configuration-in-complex-projects/) ). Does that help?

Comment: @user944849: Gold!  I have been using Apache Maven for years.  I never knew about this option, but I needed it today.  Thank you to share.

Answer (score 1):

You could define your test source directory using a property, and override it using a custom profile, like this:

```
<properties>
    <test.dir>src/test/java</test.dir>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>benchmark</id>
        <properties>
            <test.dir>src/benchmark-tests/java</test.dir>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <testSourceDirectory>${test.dir}</testSourceDirectory>
</build>
```

This way, executing `mvn test` would run all your tests inside **src/test/java** and `mvn test -Pbenchmark` would run the tests inside **src/benchmark-tests/java**.

Console output:

```
mvn clean test
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running br.com.instaweb.sample.SampleUnitTest
sample unit test was run
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.034 sec
```

and:

```
mvn clean test -Pbenchmark
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running br.com.stackoverflow.BenchmarkTest
benchmark test was run
```

Comment: By the attempted solution, OP wants to run *all* tests when the profile is enabled, not the benchmark tests alone.